# How to export animated curve from blender to unity

Tags: animation, unity, curve-modifier

I needed to make an animated scroll for a project, so I followed this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOZ-LYFtCGI, I followed all the steps and got decent results in blender, but when I tried to export the model as an fbx file for unity, the animation gets messed up. Only the scroll handle moves and not the plane. I don't understand what mistake I have made, if I could get some insights, I shall be delighted. Thank You.
I have uploaded the model on sketchfab, so maybe someone could check the model itself and tell me what's wrong.
Model link - https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/x-3-02cb1a27a0f143928aad001507ef8f2b

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see (and what I know from having completed a Blender to Unity project recently) the root of your trouble is the active modifiers that you're using for the effect (the mirror and the curve modifiers).

To my knowledge, you cannot export a Blender Modifier via an FBX. It will either ignore it and erase any other modifiers below it on the list or (if you have 'Apply Modifiers' ticked in your FBX export settings, under Geometry) it will apply them. I found this out when I had a Subdivision modifier on a rig I was using and it caused a lot of trouble for a short while.

My limited advice would be to try using an alembic cache export instead of an FBX, because that will cache all the animation data to the mesh.

Otherwise, you could try and apply your modifiers before your export, but I presume that will undo the effect you're going for?

If you're simply looking for the scroll to stretch out in the middle and the two ends to move apart, I suggest animating the middle section in a different way, e.g. using shape keys or through an 'Anim All' Add On which will allow you to animate vertex points; or just by using two joints.

Hope that helps. Sorry I don't have a straight answer!